# How to resolve compatibility issue when using both Gradle and Maven builds in Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, gradle

I have a Spring Boot application with the following project structure:

Main

- serverModule
- coreModule

Initially, I set up my project using Gradle and everything was working fine with my dependencies. However, I'm now trying to add the same dependencies to my Maven build as well to have both Gradle and Maven builds side by side.

The issue I'm facing is that I'm getting a compatibility error when I build with Maven. The error message says:

**incompatible types: @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest cannot be converted to jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest**

I understand that the error is related to the use of different servlet classes by different versions of the validation library. However, I'm not sure how to resolve this issue so that I can use both Gradle and Maven builds without any compatibility issues.

I have tried the following steps so far:

- Adding Jakarta instead of Java
- Copying exact versions from my Gradle build
- Adding the Java dependency for validation in Maven (whereas in Gradle, implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation' was enough to provide validation)
- Updating the OkHttp dependency to com.squareup.okhttp3 in Maven (whereas in Gradle, implementation 'com.c.okhttp3:okhttp:4.10.0' was working alright)

However, I'm still unable to resolve this compatibility error and use both Gradle and Maven builds without any issues.

Can someone please suggest a solution to resolve this error and help me set up both Gradle and Maven builds for my Spring Boot application? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the reason you want to set up a Gradle and a Maven build? This is an unusual requirement.

Comment: I have been assigned this task.

Comment: Please explain to us the background behind this assignment. Why is it useful in your case?

Comment: To make comparison between gradle and maven build in terms of efficiency. It's mandatory that I do it on same project.

Comment: Then I would create two git branches of the same project, one with Gradle and one with Maven. This allows you to compare efficiency without having to use both at once.

Comment: Even if I do that, this issue persists. incompatible types, because dependancies are same

Comment: Based on what I see is that you seemed to be using different versions of dependencies because of the differences jakarta/javax... I would analyse the dependency tree exactly... and see what the used transitive dependencies are... I expect there are some differences...